# model size check

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I've had some success passing query results to my view.

Unfortunately the ASP/Razor code balks in the foreach when the resulting model list has 0 entries.

```
@foreach (var action in (List<LemonTrader.Models.Lemon>)ViewData["lemons"]) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.Encode( action.acidity)
```

If there are no entries it says something about a null exception.

What is the best way to handle the case where the list is empty?

I guess I could put a code block in and have it do an if/then branch. This seems to deviate a bit from the elegant razor one-liner of @foreach.

I guess I could put blank stuff in the controller and then just display something blank.

Those don't seem like very elegant approaches.

Any better ideas?

Comment: That's funny ... for some reason it seems to handle it gracefully now. I don't think I changed anything ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try do next:

1. Create additional  model (viewmodel) in Models folder (for example LemonsView.cs) and put there:

   `public class LemonList
   {
    public IQueryable<Lemon> AllLemons { get; set; }
   }`
2. Create a controller (LemonController.cs)

   `public ActionResult Lemons`
       `{`
           `var model = new LemonList();`
           `var lemons = db.Lemon;`

   ```
       model.AllLemons = lemons;
       return View(model);
   }`
   ```
3. In View:

   `@using LemonTrader.Models.AllLemon`s
       `foreach(var item in Model.LemonList)`{
         `@item.Some`
       `}`

If in result you will have null, it will be a blank page

Have fun!

Comment: Thanks! I think I'll add this to my controller class. Writing classes to carry other classes around is not agile enough for me.

Comment: You are welcome! :) You also can check in controller is model null and show anouther view if it is true (for example 404 page). Just change return statment to this:  return model == null ? View(model) : View("404view");